# How can i update my image in edit form in asp .net mvc????Input field is not accepting image file from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is how i am doing it!!!

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    <div class="panel-body" style="margin-top:10px;">
       <div style="height:100%;width:20%;float:left;margin-top:100px;">
           <h3>Select a file to upload at previous one:</h3>
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.file)
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.file,new{@src="data:image/png;
           base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ImageData,0,
           Model.ImageData.Length)" ,type="file"})
           @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
        </div>
     </div>
```

But this is giving validation error something like this.

**Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. The validation errors are: Please select a file**

Comment: You cannot set the value of a file input programatically for security reasons - it can only be set by the user selecting a file

Comment: And an input does not have a `src` attribute. What exactly are you trying to do, and what is the code in your controller methods?

Comment: You may have `Required` attribute for `file` property which throwing validation exception due to file input should not bound to any property. Remove it, instead use `Required` attribute only for string property containing returned file name.